# Execute a PHP function in a form action

Tags: php, function

I have a html/php page `index.php` with prior code and functions however there is a function that prompts the user to change its password if its expired.

I want when the user clicks the change password button it calls the `changepassword()` function(all code located on the same page). Problem I am having is when the user clicks the `change password` button it defaults back to the login screen. I'm guessing its a result of the `action="index.php"`attribute.

How do i get the button to directly call the function and not doing a `action="index.php"` which will always default back to the login page?
here is a synapses of the code

```
$oldpassword = $_POST["oldpassword"];
        $newpassword = $_POST["newpassword"];
        $confirmpassword = $_POST["confirmpassword"];

        $passwordResult = '';

        if($_POST["update"] == "user")
        {
                $passwordResult = ChangePassword($db_connection, $userid, $_POST["oldpassword"], $_POST["newpassword"], $_POST["confirmpassword"]);
        }       
        echo'
                  <div class="dataform">
            <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <table>
            <tr><td>
            Old Password:
            </td><td>
            <input type="password" name="oldpassword" value=""/><br/>
            </td></tr><tr><td>
            New Password:
            </td><td>
            <input type="password" name="newpassword" value=""/><br/>
            </td></tr><tr><td>
            Confirm Password:
            </td><td>
            <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" value=""/><br/>
            </td></tr><tr><td>
            <input type="submit" value="Change Password"/>
            </td></tr>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="update" value="user"/>
            </form>
            '.$passwordResult.'
            </div>';                    
        }
```

Change password function:

```
function ChangePassword($db_connection, $userid, $old, $new, $confirm)
    {

        if($confirm != $new)
        {
            echo '<font color="red">The confirmation password does not match the new password.</font>';
            return;
        }   

        $qrystring = 'UPDATE user
                    SET password = SHA1(?)
                    WHERE userid = ?
                    AND password = SHA1(?)';

        if ($statement = $db_connection->prepare($qrystring)) 
        {
            $statement->bind_param('sss', $new, $userid, $old);

            $statement->execute();

            $reportid = $db_connection->insert_id;

            if($statement->affected_rows != 0)
            {

                $db_connection->commit();
                echo $header_string.'
                            <font color="green"><b>Your password was successfully updated.</b></font><br/>';
            }
            else
            {
                $db_connection->rollback();
                echo $header_string.'
                <font color="red">We were unable to update your password. Please verify that the old password is correct.<i>(u3)</i></font><br/>';
            }

            $statement->close();
        }
        else
        {
            $db_connection->rollback();
            echo $header_string.'
            <font color="red">We were unable to update your password at this time.<i>(u4)</i></font><br/>';
        }

    }
```

Comment: don't post to `index.php` if thats not where you want to handle the change request .. you can just leave it as `action=""` if you want to post to self url.

Comment: all code is on index.php

Comment: as i stated before there are other functions on the page so when the change pasword button is pressed it simply refreshes back to login

Comment: Then you need something to account for `isLoggedIn` so as not to throw login promt.. I would rethink your approach and try keep it simple.

Comment: Move the change password PHP into its own file and call that file when the action is required.

Comment: so there is no way to directly link the change password button to the function?

Comment: @dames you could use javascript's ajax to take the form details and post elsewhere without the refreshing.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX but i think you have underlying issues with your structure if everything is on the index.

Comment: You could directly link, but it is more trouble than it is worth. Doing it the way I suggest also helps to decouple your PHP from your HTML, makes it easier to add things like JavaScript and in general is a good practice. Truth is that the code could have been moved and tested in less  time than it took for us to make these comments.

Comment: Client-side javascript cannot "directly call" into server-side php functions. There has to be a request that triggers the webserver to spawn another php instance that handles the request. No request to handle -> no php instance [ ...in the common webserver scenario; yes of course there are other possibilities, but they are rather unlikely in the context of the question ;-) ] - therefore `all code located on the same page` is more wrong than right: From the webbrowser's view _there is no function_ ChangePassword(). Open the source code view in your browser; that's all there is for the client.